# Linux Shell Script For Each File in a Directory Grab the filename and execute a program

Tags: linux, shell

Scenario :

A folder in Linux system. I want to loop through every .xls file in a folder.

This folder typically consists of various folders, various filetypes (.sh, .pl,.csv,...).

All I want to do is loop through **all files in the root** and execute a program only on .xls files.

Edit :

The problem is the program I have to execute is 'xls2csv' to convert from .xls to .csv format. So, for each .xls file I have to grab the filename and append it to .csv.

For instance, I have a test.xls file and the arguments fro xls2csv are : `xls2csv test.xls test.csv`

Did I make sense?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

bash:

```
for f in *.xls ; do xls2csv "$f" "${f%.xls}.csv" ; done
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for for a completely different reason. A little editing, and it’s perfect for my specific need. Thanks =D
  
And for anyone who isn’t clear on what this does: ${f%.ext} substitutes the filename without the extension, so in this example, it’d render to "filename.csv" rather than "filename.xls.csv".

Comment: Heh I Googled "linux foreach txt file" and found this. This was exactly what I needed, I was actually trying to use xls2csv but figured I wouldn't find any results searching for that :)

Comment: $f will have a value of *.xls if the *.xls doesn't match any file. Check my answer if that's a problem.

Comment: Or you could just set `nullglob` in order to skip the loop.

Comment: Works great! I use it with 7-zip to archive each file separately when necessary. You can also set up this logic in combination with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310251/alias-with-input-unix) if you use this function often.

Comment: How to make that script work recursively for all subfolders?

Answer (score 22):

```
for i in *.xls ; do 
  [[ -f "$i" ]] || continue
  xls2csv "$i" "${i%.xls}.csv"
done
```

The first line in the `do` checks if the "matching" file really exists, because in case nothing matches in your `for`, the `do` will be executed with "*.xls" as `$i`. This could be horrible for your `xls2csv`.

Answer (score 17):

Look at the [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command.

What you are looking for is something like

```
find . -name "*.xls" -type f -exec program
```

Post edit

```
find . -name "*.xls" -type f -exec xls2csv '{}' '{}'.csv;
```

will execute  `xls2csv file.xls file.xls.csv`

Closer to what you want.

Comment: `find -maxdepth 1` to exclude subfolders.  This also converts `test.xls` to `test.xls.csv` instead of `test.csv`.  So not *quite* what OP asked for, but pretty close.

Comment: Using `{}` as a substring of an argument rather than an entire argument is a GNU extension, not guaranteed by the POSIX spec for `find`. As such, this answer isn't necessarily portable to non-GNU platforms.

Answer (score 6):

```
find . -type f -name "*.xls" -printf "xls2csv %p %p.csv\n" | bash
```

bash 4 (recursive)

```
shopt -s globstar
for xls in /path/**/*.xls
do
  xls2csv "$xls" "${xls%.xls}.csv"
done
```

Comment: Excellent solution.  I've used this to allow me to write haml/scss and build into html/css at design-time for a node.js project.

Comment: This is outright dangerous if you don't trust your filenames not to contain things like `$(rm -rf /)`... or just whitespace.