# Need to grep for first occurrences of multiple strings

Tags: grep

I am attempting to return the first occurrence of multiple strings, ie, I want to select the lines from the following text where the first occurrence of 1259, 3009, and 1589 happen.

```
ADWN    1259    11:00   B23

ADWN    3009    12:00   B19

DDWN     723    11:30   B04

ADWN    1589    14:20   B12

ADWN    1259    11:10   B23

DDWN    2534    13:00   B16

ADWN    3009    11:50   B14
```

This gives me all matches:

```
grep '1259\|3009\|1589'  somelog.log
```

And this gives me only the first match

```
grep -m 1  '1259\|3009\|1589'  somelog.log
```

I want to return the following:

```
ADWN    1259    11:00   B23

ADWN    3009    12:00   B19

ADWN    1589    14:20   B12
```

I think that creating a file with the required values, and then looping through the file, passing each number individually into the grep command will give me what I am looking for, but I haven't found an example of this.  Is there a simple solution for this, is a loop the best way to handle this, or has this example already been answered elsewhere?

Thanks in advance for your ideas and suggestions--

Clyde

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '!array[$2]++ && $2 ~ /^1259$|^3009$|^1589$/' file.txt
```

Results:

```
ADWN    1259    11:00   B23
ADWN    3009    12:00   B19
ADWN    1589    14:20   B12
```

***edit:***

I should really get into the habit of reading the whole question first. I see that you're thinking of creating a file with the values you'd like to find the first occurrence of. Put these in a file called `values.txt` with one value per line. For example; here's the contents of `values.txt`:

```
1259
3009
1589
```

Then run this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$0]++; next } $2 in array { print; delete array[$2] }' values.txt file.txt
```

Results:

```
ADWN    1259    11:00   B23
ADWN    3009    12:00   B19
ADWN    1589    14:20   B12
```

---

1st command explanation:

If the second column (`$2`) equals one of those three values listed, add it to the array if it's not already in there. `awk` prints the whole line by default.

2nd command explanation:

`FNR` is number of records relative to the current input file.
`NR` is the total number of records.

The `FNR==NR { ... }` construct is only true for the first input file. So for each of the lines in `values.txt`, we add the whole line (`$0`) to an array (I've called it array, but you could give it another name). `next` forces `awk` to read the next line in `values.txt` (and skip processing the rest of the command). When `FNR==NR` is no longer true, the second file in the arguments list is read. We then check for the second column (`$2`)in the array,  if it's in there, print it and remove it from the array. By using `delete` we essentially set a max count of one.

Comment: Steve--thanks, that is doing what I asked, it is returning the first occurrence of each value. I've got some reading to do on awk, and understand specifically what the code is doing

Comment: Nice, I appreciate the explanation--some of this stuff can be pretty opaque!  I'll definitely be able to put this to good use, thanks again!

Comment: No problem. If I've left something out, or you need a little more explanation/help please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It might not work depending on your grep version:

```
 grep -m 1 -e pattern1 -e pattern2
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, this snippet only returned the first pattern, thanks though.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use for each (see [Linux Shell Script For Each File in a Directory Grab the filename and execute a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297510/linux-shell-script-for-each-file-in-a-directory-grab-the-filename-and-execute-a))
For each pattern you want to match execute a separate grep concatenating to the output file

Comment: That's the idea I was thinking about, thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

This one will work too.

```
for i in $(cut -d " " -f1 somelog.log | sort -u); do LC_ALL=C fgrep -m1 "$i" somelog.log; done
```