# Recursive Search of Multiple Occurrences of Multiple Strings

Tags: search, recursion, awk, grep, gawk

This question is a direction extension of a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204958/need-to-grep-for-first-occurrences-of-multiple-strings). My search requirements are provided below

The multiple strings that needed to be searched are stored in a file values.txt (the Input File) which for example contains information as follows

```
string1  1
string2  3
string3  5
```

- where the first column (string1, string2, string3) indicate the strings that
  needs to be searched while the second column indicates the number of
  occurrences to be searched.
- Further the search needs to be performed recursively on files with a 
  specific file extension (ex .out, .txt etc.)
- The search output should be directed to a file where the outputs of the search are printed along with the file-names and their path.

For example the typical output must look like the one given below (for a recursive search of fileNames with extension .out)

```
<path_of_searched_file1/fileName1.out>
The full line containing the <first> instance of <string1>
The full line containing the <first> instance of <string2>
The full line containing the <second> instance of <string2>
The full line containing the <third> instance of <string2>
The full line containing the <first> instance of <string3>
The full line containing the <second> instance of <string3>
The full line containing the <third> instance of <string3>
The full line containing the <fourth> instance of <string3>
The full line containing the <fifth> instance of <string3>


<path_of_searched_file2/fileName2.out>
The full line containing the <first> instance of <string1>
The full line containing the <first> instance of <string2>
The full line containing the <second> instance of <string2>
The full line containing the <third> instance of <string2>
The full line containing the <first> instance of <string3>
The full line containing the <second> instance of <string3>
The full line containing the <third> instance of <string3>
The full line containing the <fourth> instance of <string3>
The full line containing the <fifth> instance of <string3>


and so on
```

Is using awk the best way to solve this search problem? If so can someone help me to modify the awk code that is provided in this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204958/need-to-grep-for-first-occurrences-of-multiple-strings) to satisfy my current search requirements.

Comment: Can you please elaborate by what you mean by _number of occurrences to be searched_? Is that per file? per line?

Comment: Hi for example value1 must be searched for only for the first occurence in the file. value2 must be searched for the first three occurences and value3 for first 5 occurences.

Comment: Post some SMALL sample input and expected output.

Comment: @Morton I have edited the question to provide sample I/O that I expect

Comment: I do not have the necessary privilege to comment on the original question that I have linked. It will be helpful if someone can comment on my behalf on the original thread to see if the same people can answer this question.

Comment: How do you define an occurrence? Please answer Jaypal's question. Also, how would you treat `value3` vs `value33`?

Comment: I believe my usage of value1 was a cause of confusion. The value1 is just means a string that I need to search which can be of any alphanumeric combination. I changed it to string1 to avoid confusion. I hope this answers the question. If not please let me know what exactly you expect.

Comment: Ok, so you're just looking for a string. That answered my second question. Now please answer my first one; i.e. what happens when there are two strings on the same line? Do you count once or twice?

Comment: Suppose <string1> and <string2> are present in the same line. At this point it is suffice to sequentially search through the files for the relevant strings. This I believe would translate it to counting it once for <string1> and once for <string2>. However if possible I would also prefer to learn to use it like an OR logic, which counts only once even though two strings are present in the same line.

Comment: I might leave you to implement that OR logic. I've added a solution that should help. It implements _most_ of what you're asking for.

Comment: @Steve Thank you very much. I will implement this to my needs in a few hours and then accept your answer. Also it will be of help if you can point out to a couple of references (preferably online) regarding awk programming in your answer. This will enable me and probably others to learn more about awk programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`; YMMV. Run like:

```
awk -f ./script.awk values.file $(find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(txt\|doc\|etc\)$")
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FNR==NR {
    a[$1]=$2;
    next
}

FNR==1 {
    for (i in a) {
        b[i]=a[i]
    }
}

{
    for (j in b) {
        if ($0 ~ j && b[j]-- > 0) {
            print > FILENAME ".out"
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$2; next } FNR==1 { for (i in a) b[i]=a[i] } { for (j in b) if ($0 ~ j && b[j]-- > 0) print > FILENAME ".out" }' values.file $(find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(txt\|doc\)$")
```

---

Explanation:

In the first block, create an associate array with the first column of `values.file` as the keys and the second column as the values. The second and third blocks read in the files found using the `find` command. The array formed in the first block is duplicated (there's no easy way to do this using `awk`; so perhaps Perl and the `Find::File::Rule` module would be a better choice?) for each file found. In the third block, we loop loop over each key searching for the string and decrementing it's value, printing to the file's location with the '.out' extension.

Comment: As requested, my learning suggestions: I started [here](http://bashshell.net/stream-filtering-utilities/exercise-1-learning-awk-basics/) and finished the tutorial. I then began reading and answering questions on SO under this tag. I would highly recommend to anyone wanting to learn `awk`, to start doing the same. On this site, there's heaps of expert 'awkers' that will help get you on track. Besides, the more people that contribute to this site, the less work I have to do. Here's another [reference](http://awk.info/?Learn). HTH.