# Alias with input. Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, alias, csh

Consider the following command.

```
grep -rn "someString" . --color
```

And I want to alias it in my `.cshrc` and perform the command like this:

```
myGrep someString
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried alias mygrep='grep something..... '

Comment: `csh` doesn't have functions, which is why aliases can accept parameters. (Or maybe `csh` doesn't have functions *because* aliases can accept parameters; I'm not sure about cause and effect here.)

Comment: Ugh. I though aliases accepted parameters; apparently, you just use history expansion to access arguments from the command prior to its alias expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csh` records your command in its history list prior to expanding aliases, so you can use history expansion to access arguments to the alias when it is used.

```
% alias myGrep grep -rn \!:1 . --color
```

When you use `myGrep foo`, that two-word command is recorded in history, then it is expanded to `grep -rn !:1 . --color`. In that command, `!:1` refers to the first argument of the previous command (`myGrep foo`), resulting in `grep -rn foo . --color`, which is actually executed.

Answer (score -2):

The proper way to make an alias that takes a parameter is with a function. In Bash functions the arguments are assessed as `$1`, `$2` and so forth. Strung concatenation is implicit. Consider:

```
hello() {
    echo 'Hello' $1
}
```

I is simply called like this:

```
$ hello Eduard
Hello Eduard
```

Comment: `csh` doesn't have functions.